# How to exclude specific SonarQube issues by file contents

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

Using SonarQube 4.1.1 on Maven based Java project.

I have a few rules that I want to exclude on specific Java files.

Here are my use cases:-

1. Exclude a set of issues
2. That set of issues must be excluded only when the files have some regular expression.
3. I do not want to blanket exclude the issues - i.e. I intend to catch these issues in other files.
4. I do not want blanket exclude the files i.e. I intend to catch other issues on these files.

I don't see any option as to how to accomplish this using Exclusions on the SonarQube Dashboard.

[image: somewhat close but these do not meet my use cases]

**Question**:

What are my options to address my use cases other than (obviously) exclude these on a case by case basis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is indeed not covered. This is a combination of the different exclusion modes that currently exist, but SonarQube does not provide such a detailled exclusion mechanism.

Comment: Feel free to comment and vote for https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5122. I have the same needs!